# Replace Value with String Match in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

df:

```
Item_Key   Item_Name   Delivery_Partner    Ex_Delivery_Partner
10001      Brush       zen                 zen and company
10002      sandle      randv               randv ltd
10003      chemical    ABC                 zen and company
10004      chair       hank                hank solution
10005      shoes       zen                 tour and zen ltd
10006      shoes       XYZ                 tour and zen ltd
10007      ropes       delv.com            delv.com
10008      ropes       hans ltd            delv.com and Enterprises
```

output:

```
Item_Key   Item_Name   Delivery_Partner    Ex_Delivery_Partner
10001      Brush       zen                 zen and company
10002      sandle      randv               randv ltd
10003      chemical    zen                 zen and company
10004      chair       hank                hank solution
10005      shoes       zen                 tour and zen ltd
10006      shoes       zen                 tour and zen ltd
10007      ropes       delv.com            delv.com 
10008      ropes       delv.com            delv.com and Enterprises
```

I need to replace "Delivery_Partner" name by checking names in "Ex_Delivery_Partner".
If there is no string match, it get replaced by "Ex_Delivery_Partner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test membership between both columns by `in` statement in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or list comprehension and then set new values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x['Delivery_Partner'] in x['Ex_Delivery_Partner'], 1)

df['Delivery_Partner'] = df['Delivery_Partner'].where(mask, df['Ex_Delivery_Partner'])
print (df)
   Item_Key Item_Name  Delivery_Partner Ex_Delivery_Partner
0     10001     Brush               zen     zen and company
1     10002    sandle             randv           randv ltd
2     10003  chemical   zen and company     zen and company
3     10004     chair              hank       hank solution
4     10005     shoes               zen    tour and zen ltd
5     10006     shoes  tour and zen ltd    tour and zen ltd
6     10007     ropes          delv.com            delv.com
```

---

```
mask = [x not in y for x, y in df[['Delivery_Partner', 'Ex_Delivery_Partner']].to_numpy()]

df.loc[mask, 'Delivery_Partner'] = df['Ex_Delivery_Partner']
print (df)
   Item_Key Item_Name  Delivery_Partner Ex_Delivery_Partner
0     10001     Brush               zen     zen and company
1     10002    sandle             randv           randv ltd
2     10003  chemical   zen and company     zen and company
3     10004     chair              hank       hank solution
4     10005     shoes               zen    tour and zen ltd
5     10006     shoes  tour and zen ltd    tour and zen ltd
6     10007     ropes          delv.com            delv.com
```

Comment: i have updated the question please look into it, what if i needed the short name from "Delivery_Partner" which is used for other items.